# How to setup a test domain which points to my Controller runs locally

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a C# controller which is running at port 44347. And when I go to browser locally https://127.0.0.0.1:44347/myurl, it hits my Controller runs on the same machine.

I want to setup so that I can when I load https://mytest.mycom.com:44347/myurl locally, it hits my controller run locally.

I have added 'mytest.mycom.com 127.0.0.1' to my hosts file in Windows. And I verify that ping mytest.mycom.com , it has reply.

But when I go https://mytest.mycom.com:44347/myurl locally, I get message saying 'mytest.mycom.com' took too long to respond.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the url that your application uses within launchSettings.config (under the properties folder). Following is an example -

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39655/",
      "sslPort": 44340
    }
  },
```

Changing "applicationUrl" will allow you to use your test domain locally.

Comment: Thanks @bsod_.  I try chaning the launchSettings.json to.  `https://mytest.mycom.com:44347` and click 'Debug'. when i try to launch my browser. IT does not able to load  `https://mytest.mycom.com:44347/swagger`